# Pre-filling values into a form by taking values from the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how my website's URL looks like

> [www.mywebsite.com/referrals/#referralcode](http://www.mywebsite.com/referrals/#referralcode)

Is there any way in which I can extract the `referralcode` part from the URL and use it to pre-fill a input value in my form. Here is the code for the input field

```
<input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Referrer Code"
          onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)}
        />
```

Here the onChange function is taking the value if user inputs something, if I set this state to the URL part by default, it is getting stored but it is not showing up in the input tag. Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a url as follows

```
www.mywebsite.com/referrals/#referralcode
```

You can get the referral code in the browser using [window.location.hash](http://window.location.hash)

Since you are using reactjs, you can use useState and useEffect to achieve what you want..

```
const Component = () => {
   const [ code, setCode ] = useState(null)

   useEffect(() => {
       if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window?.location?.hash) {
           setCode(window.location.hash?.slice(1)) //use slice to remove the # at the beginning
       }

   },[]) //<-- load only once

   return <input
          type="text"
          value={code}
          placeholder="Referrer Code"
          onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)}
        />

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.hash` will return `"#referralcode"`

```html
<input
   type="text"
   placeholder="Referrer Code"
   value = window.location.hash.slice(1)
   onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, you can use React Router Dom's `useLocation`hook:

```js
let location = useLocation();
console.log(location.split("#")[1])
```